# não consigo inserir os valores na tabela com auto_increment na chave primária

Tags: mysql

Esta é a minha tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Utilizadores(
IDUtilizador INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PNome VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
UNome VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
PalavraPasse VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
TipoUtilizador VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
Check(TipoUtilizador='Administrador' OR TipoUtilizador='Cliente'),
PRIMARY KEY(IDUtilizador)
);
```

Este é o meu Insert:

```
INSERT INTO Utilizadores (IDUtilizador,PNome,UNome,Email,PalavraPasse,TipoUtilizador) VALUES ('Ruben','Figueiredo','RubenFigueiredo@gmail.com','RubenFigueiredo','Cliente');
```

o erro que me dá é o seguinte:

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Não precisa vc passar o `IDUtilizador` não, se ele é auto-icrement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na coluna auto-increment você pode omitir ela da field list e da clásula `VALUES` ou passar `null` como valor.

Passar uma string vazia pode funcionar dependendo da configuração do [NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) que se estiver ativo, permitirá o valor zero na coluna e ao encontrar a string vazia tentará inserir o registro sempre com zero o que causa o erro de duplicação de chave primária, nesse caso para ter o comportamento correto apenas `null` incrementa o valor.

Opção 1

```
INSERT INTO Utilizadores ( IDUtilizador,PNome,UNome,Email,PalavraPasse,TipoUtilizador) VALUES (null, 'Ruben','Figueiredo','RubenFigueiredo@gmail.com','RubenFigueiredo','Cliente');
```

Opção 2

```
 INSERT INTO Utilizadores (PNome,UNome,Email,PalavraPasse,TipoUtilizador) VALUES ('Ruben','Figueiredo','RubenFigueiredo@gmail.com','RubenFigueiredo','Cliente');
```

Answer (score 3):

Modo Correto:

```
INSERT INTO Utilizadores (IDUtilizador,PNome,UNome,Email,PalavraPasse,TipoUtilizador) VALUES ('', 'Ruben','Figueiredo','RubenFigueiredo@gmail.com','RubenFigueiredo','Cliente');
```

Você precisa na hora de passar o ID, passar ele como `NULL` (''), pra que o auto_increment funcione corretamente. Dessa forma, ele irá indexar os ids