# Não consigo adicionar valores com a Procedure no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um trabalho com banco de dados MySQL e estou com dificuldades na *procedure* criada:

```
DELIMITER $$
drop Procedure if exists cad_cat$$
CREATE PROCEDURE cad_cat(pnomeCat varchar(60))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Categorias VALUES(pnomeCat);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Eu não entendi esse erro, alguém pode me explicar?

```
call cad_cat('frutas');
```

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Parece que a sua tabela `Categorias` possui mais de uma coluna e você está tentando inserir apenas um valor. O erro basicamente diz que não coincide as quantidades de colunas da tabela com a quantidade de valores que você informou.

Comment: Tem dois campos id e nome, mas o id eu deixei como auto increment.

Comment: create table Categorias(
id_categoria int primary key auto_increment not null,
nome varchar(60) not null)engine=InnoDB charset=utf8;

Comment: Sem especificar que você quer apenas informar o nome, você precisa especificar que o valor de id será o *default*. Ou informar que será apenas a coluna `nome` que será especificada.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o erro :)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [não consigo inserir os valores na tabela com auto\_increment na chave primária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129761/n%c3%a3o-consigo-inserir-os-valores-na-tabela-com-auto-increment-na-chave-prim%c3%a1ria)